Diophantine equation $(5a)^2+(12b)^2=(13c)^2$
I'm looking for a way to find unequal positive integer solutions for the equation $(5a)^2+(12b)^2=(13c)^2$.  This problem comes from an attempt to find any solution by hand for an older Project Euler problem asking to find an optimal solution.  So far, all I'm attempted was to see if there were any solutions for $b=18$.  This then became $(13c+5a)(13c-5a)=216^2$.  If $13c-5a=k,13c+5a=\frac{6^6}k$.  I found that for $a$ and $c$ to be integers, $k$ would have to be equivalent to $\pm14$ or $\pm64\pmod{130}$.  Looking for factors of $6^6$ less than $216$ meeting this criteria, I found $2$ possibilities.  $64$ looked promising, but $\frac{6^6}{64}$ is odd and did not yield an integer solution.  The only value that did somewhat work was $k=144$, which unfortunately led to $a=b=c=18$.  A decent amount of work to end up nowhere.
Any better ways to attempt this?  Next thing I'll try will probably be to rewrite $13c$ as the sum of 2 squares to see if I can use the paramaterization of pythagorean triples ($13c=m^2+n^2$,etc) to find solutions.

you know one solution (1,1,1).  All rational solutions come from writing  integer variables $p,q,r$   and a rational  one to solve for called $t,$   with $a = 1 + tp,  b = 1 + tq, c= 1 + tr.$  Then solve for $t$  using your equation, finally plug back in, the result being rational formulas for $a,b,c$ in variables $p,q,r$

One may then multiply through by the common denominator. It is more work to get all integer solutions, but it can be done. Instead of a single formula as in Pythagorean Triples, there are a finite number  of them required to cover all integer solutions.

I found a family that includes the known $(1,1,1).$  The expressions for $a,b$  factor over the integers
$$ a =  u^2 - 24336  v^2 = (u+156v)(u-156v) $$
$$ b = u^2 + 338vu + 24336v^2 = (u+104v)(u+234v) $$
$$ c = u^2 + 288vu + 24336v^2 = (u+144v)^2 +(60v)^2$$
and then $25a^2 + 144 b^2 = 169 c^2 $
with $c < 110$  and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1 $
     0    13    12
     1     1     1
    13     0     5
    53   116   109
    64   105   100
    81    88    87
    91    13    37
    99    70    75
   112    57    68
   117    26    51
   117    65    75
   119    50    65
   133    36    61
   143    52    73
   144    25    60
   155    14    61
   169    78    97
   176     7    68
   189    20    75
   207    38    87
   208    65   100
   224    55   100
   235    66   109

The additional Pythagorean type parametrizations come from cases where $\gcd(u,v)= 1$  but $\gcd(a,b,c) > 1.$  Then dividing through by that $g$ gives a primitive triple of smaller numbers.  From the variety of values of $g,$   quite a large number of parametrizations   would be required to cover all  solutions of the original problem.
   g=GCD        a/g      b/g       c/g    g      u     v           
     1           1         1         1     1     1     0
   300         -81        88        87   300     6     1
   240         -99        70        75   240    24    -1
   360         -64       105       100   360    36     1
   195        -117        65        75   195    39    -1
   200        -112        57        68   200    44    -1
   180        -119        50        65   180    54    -1
   400         -53       116       109   400    56     1
   144        -133        36        61   144    72    -1
   156        -117        26        51   156    78    -1
   120        -144        25        60   120    84    -1
   100        -155        14        61   100    94    -1
   g=GCD        a/g      b/g       c/g    g      u     v 

The theorem is in Mordell, Diophantine Equations.


I see you've put in a lot of work into this, but I'm not sure I see where all this stuff comes from.  I see the substitution you have in the comment is similar, but not identical, to the theorem you copied.  I have not yet tried the substitution for myself yet (is that where those quadratics in u and v came from?), though I did try the paramaterization method, which did seem to provide a simple solution.  I will probably add it as an answer later.

By using chord - tangent method,I approach this problem Algebraically
Consider,
$$25a^2+144b^2=169c^2$$
Where $abc$ is non zero Integer
Dividing by  $c^2$  on both sides,
Take  $$x=\frac{a}{c}$$
&  $$y=\frac{b}{c}$$
We get,
$25x^2+144y^2=169$  --->(1)
Wkt (x,y)=(1,1) is a known solution
Take $$y-1=m(x-1)$$ where m is a rational number
$y=m(x-1)+1$
Put y in (1) & After simplifying we get
$(25+144m^2)x^2+(-288m^2+288m)x+(144m^2-288m-25)=0$
Wkt $x=1$ is already a known solution
So by Factoring $x-1$ we get
$$[x-1][(25+144m^2)x-144m^2+288m+25]=0$$
Solving above equation for $x$ & discard $x=1$ because $x=1$ is already a known solution so we get
$$x=\frac{144m^2-288m-25}{144m^2+25}$$
Substitute $x$ in $y$ we get
$$y=\frac{-144m^2-50m+25}{144m^2+25}$$
Let $$m=\frac{p}{q}$$
substitute $m$ in $x$ & $y$ then we get
$$x=\frac{144p^2-288pq-25q^2}{144p^2+25q^2}=\frac{a}{c}$$
$$y=\frac{-144p^2-50pq+25q^2}{144p^2+25q^2}=\frac{b}{c}$$
Hence we get a two parameter solution:
$a=144p^2-288pq-25q^2$
$b= -144p^2-50pq+25q^2$
$c=144p^2+25q^2$

I did eventually try the paramaterization of Pythagorean triples to come up with a surprisingly simple solution to this, although it relies on the resulting Pythagorean triple being primitive.  Apparently, I didn't consider the case when gcd(a,b,c)=1, but the 3 squares do share a prime.  In any case, solutions for primitive Pythagorean triples can be generated by $$a=m^2-n^2,b=2mn,c=m^2+n^2$$ where m and n are coprime and 1 is even.  For example, the $5-12-13$ triple can be generated by $(m,n)=(3,2)$.  For this problem, let $$c=u^2+v^2$$ $$13c=(2^2+3^2)(u^2+v^2)=(2u+3v)^2+(3u-2v)^2=m^2+n^2$$ $$2mn=2(2u+3v)(3u-2v)=12b,6b=(2u+3v)(3u-2v)$$
Examining this equality modulo 2 and 3 yields $uv\equiv0\pmod6$.  Finally,
$$m^2-n^2=(2u+3v)^2-(3u-2v)^2=(5u+v)(5v-u)=5a$$ $$-uv\equiv0\pmod5,uv\equiv0\pmod5$$
So it seems all it takes is for $uv$ to be a multiple of $30$.  For a relatively small solution, let's try $u=5,v=6$.  Then $$m=2u+3v=28,n=3u-2v=3$$ $$5a=m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)=31(25)$$ $$a=31(5)=155$$ $$6b=mn=84,b=14 $$ $$c=u^2+v^2=61$$
